# how to use yad2k(yolo) in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolo

thank you for reading my question.
I use google colab. and I need yad2k library. 
maybe this is not support pip.

anybody success install yad2k?

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     13 from keras.models import load_model, Model
     14 from yolo_utils import read_classes, read_anchors, generate_colors, preprocess_image, draw_boxes, scale_boxes
---> 15 from yad2k.models.keras_yolo import yolo_head, yolo_boxes_to_corners, preprocess_true_boxes, yolo_loss, yolo_body
     16 
     17 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

/content/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py in ()
     10 
     11 from utils import compose
---> 12 from .keras_darknet19 import (DarknetConv2D, DarknetConv2D_BN_Leaky, darknet_body)
     13 
     14 sys.path.append('..')

/content/yad2k/models/keras_darknet19.py in ()
      9 from keras.regularizers import l2
     10 
---> 11 from ..utils import compose
     12 
     13 # Partial wrapper for Convolution2D with static default argument.

ImportError: cannot import name 'compose'

Answer (score 3):

Use the below commands in colab

!git clone https://github.com/allanzelener/yad2k.git

from yad2k.yad2k.models.keras_yolo import yolo_head, yolo_boxes_to_corners, preprocess_true_boxes, yolo_loss, yolo_body

All the files are in yad2k>yad2k>.... so you u need to type it twice, hope ur issue is resolved